# Open select file dialog using Enter key press

Tags: javascript, html, css, input, accessibility

I have a problem with my project

I would like to open the input file on "Enter" key to improve some accessibility.

I've added tabindex on label because when I jump in to this label by using tab and press "enter" I would like to fire function which will open the input file picker.

```css
.input {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<input id="input" class="input" name="newFile" type="file" accept=".pdf" data-required="true" />
<label class="btn" for="input" tabindex="0">
  <span class="upload label">
    <span class="label__text" data-label="Upload file" data-next-label="Upload next file">Upload file</span>
  </span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Warning** the following is just a quick idea of how to achieve this by styling the actual input and visually hiding the label (to ensure it is still accessible).

However there are lots of accessibility issues you still need to consider, showing which file was selected for example.

But this does show you how you can style the input to keep all the native functionality without having to re implement it yourself (active state for example, which I styled here). Also don't forget a custom focus indicator, `input:focus::before`.

There are other issues such as browser support to consider as well, however in theory this should fall back reasonably gracefully, I just haven't tested it.

[This codepen](https://codepen.io/accessabilly/pen/qNpZJg) gives a good starting point on how to implement some of the features this is missing such as showing the file name selected.

```css
input{
  color: transparent;
  width:150px;
  height:28px
}
input::-webkit-file-upload-button {
  visibility: hidden;
}
input::before {
  content: 'Select a PDF';
  color: black;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 5px 8px;
  outline: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px #fff;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 10pt;
  width:132px;
}
input:hover::before {
  border-color: black;
}
input:active {
  outline: 0;
}
label { 
    position: absolute !important;
    height: 1px; 
    width: 1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    clip: rect(1px 1px 1px 1px); /* IE6, IE7 */
    clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
    white-space: nowrap; /* added line */
}
```

```html
<input id="input" class="input" name="newFile" type="file" accept=".pdf" data-required="true"/>
<label for="input">upload file</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a little bit of Javascript, to click the hidden `<input type="file">` element on Enter key.
I added ids to the elements so JS finds them easily:

```js
document.getElementById("fakefileinput").addEventListener("keydown", function(event){
    if(event.key == "Enter"){
        document.getElementById("input").click();
    }
});
```

```css
.input {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<input id="input" class="input" name="newFile" type="file" accept=".pdf" data-required="true" />
<label id="fakefileinput" class="btn" for="input" tabindex="0">
  <span class="upload label">
    <span class="label__text" data-label="Upload file" data-next-label="Upload next file">Upload file</span>
  </span>
</label>
```